# Raspberry Pi3 Screenly connecting via VOIP

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently stuck while trying to program a Pi3 using screenly.
When I connect via VOIP for the first time it allows me to edit the assets fine, but once the network restarts it does not allow me to access the resource editor and won't work.

Current code for this
 `auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp 
                wpa-ssid VOIP
                wpa-psk  password`
This allowed me to get it to work prior to restarting the access point
Any one got any idea how to stop this from dropping the connection once restarted?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Screenly OSE are you running? Check out [this blog post](https://www.screenly.io/blog/2018/01/19/screenly-ose-0.13-is-available/) as we simplified the way WiFi works in the most recent release.